# Customize palantir docker gradle plugin

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to migrate from Transmode gradle docker plugin to Palantir docker gradle plugin.

Old task is as below,

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    group "docker"
    push = false
    applicationName = awsContainerRepositoryName()
    dockerfile = pickDockerfile()
    tagVersion = "local"
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
            rename { String fileName ->
                fileName.replace("${jar.baseName}-${project.version}", "app")
            }
        }

        new File(stageDir, "service_version.txt").text = "${project.version}"

        copy {
            from "${buildDir}/asciidoc/html5/index.html"
            into "${stageDir}/api-documentation/"
        }

        if (project.hasProperty('customDockerRunStep')) {
            runCommand project.customDockerRunStep
        }

        exec {
            commandLine 'bash', 'shared-build/aws/retrieve_aws_ecr_login.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to add doFirst block as below,

```
docker {
    dependsOn assemble
    name awsContainerRepositoryName()
    dockerfile file(pickDockerfile())
    files bootJar.archivePath
    doFirst {
        // some code
    }
}
```

But it is giving below error,

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'service-abc'.
> No signature of method: build_dgdrt7rh9kp8lojc44jud6em6.docker() is applicable for argument types: (build_dgdrt7rh9kp8lojc44jud6em6$_run_closure7) values: [build_dgdrt7rh9kp8lojc44jud6em6$_run_closure7@8431bf9]
```

Please help

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet @arfat619